# Make [phaser.io] a synonym of [phaser-framework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently two tags that refer to the [Phaser framework](http://phaser.io/): [phaser-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework), with 632 questions; and [phaser.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser.io), with 30 questions. I think that [phaser.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser.io) should be a synonym of [phaser-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phaser.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser.io) was sometime completely retagged manually to [phaser-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phaser-framework), and no questions remain.

I don't think it is necessary to retroactively add a synonym now, so, I am marking this as complete. If a need arises in the future, we can add it easily.